# Change highlight color in vi

Tags: vi

how do I change the color used to highlight searches in vi?  Right now white letters on a yellow backgroup is completely illegible.  I'd rather it just invert the color scheme, i.e., black letter on white background or maybe have red letters on black background.  But the current color scheme is unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:hi Search guibg=Yellow guifg=Black ctermbg=Yellow ctermfg=Black`

You don't necessarily have to set both the `gui` and `cterm` values. It depends on if you're using Vi from a GUI window or from the command line terminal.

More info: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight

Comment: Note that, you should already enable highlighting for above command to work as expected using `:set hlsearch`